# What is the meaning of the phrase "comme fruit de bouche"?

Tags: vocabulaire, alimentation

I ran into this phrase on the [wikipedia page for Mandarines (oranges).](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarine) The entire sentence is:

> Les utilisations de la mandarine sont identiques à celles de l’orange. **Elle est notamment appréciée comme fruit de bouche.** L’écorce et le jus sont utilisés dans les boissons (liqueur, condiments, bière, etc.), en cuisine salée et sucrée.

I have never run into this phrase before and I even tried looking for it in idiom repositories, but I only found a slight mention to it [here](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/fruit+de+bouche.html).

What does the phrase "comme fruit de bouche" mean in this context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Fruit that you eat" or "fruit for direct consumption," as opposed to fruit for making jam, wine, liqueur, etc.

Comment: I like the answer, but were you able to find that in a dictionary?

Comment: No, that's just what the Linguee results and some common sense led me to.  :-)

Comment: For the food industry terminology, _Termium_ has it at [_fresh market fruit_](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&codom2nd=&srchtxt=FRUIT+BOUCHE); maybe contrasting with [_fruit de garniture_](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&codom2nd=&srchtxt=FRUIT+GARNITURE) along the lines you explain etc. Thanks.

Comment: +1 As you allude to, it could also be contrasted with [fruits à cidre](https://www.ipsuisse.ch/Web/Fruits_%C3%A0_cidre_id46?lang=2&ResetCache=l) (especially '[pommes à cidre](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/pomme%20%C3%A0%20cidre)' for making apple cider).